# Pass/Fail Test-Connection Into Excel

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm new to Powershell. I'm trying to automate a few things. My biggest obstacle right now is trying to get a failed Test-Connection to export into Excel with a -Foreground color. Green for "Online" and red for "Offline."

Another issue, it does ping a computer offline, it writes to the Computer Pane as multiple exceptions. Is there a way to make it do it only one time?

I would like to have the "Offline" ping in Excel (1,4).

Any help will be definitely appreciated! If you don't mind explaining how and why it works too, that would be perfect.

Thank you.

```
$Comps = Get-Content -Path "FilePath\ComputerList.txt"
$Date = Get-Date -Format MM-dd-yyyy

#Stop-Process -Name "Excel" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Suspends activity for a # of seconds.
Start-Sleep 3

$XL = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$xL.displayAlerts = $false
 
$WB = $XL.Workbooks.Add()
$WS = $WB.Worksheets.Item(1)

$WS.Cells.Item(1,1) = "Date"
$WS.Cells.Item(1,2) = "IP Address"
$WS.Cells.Item(1,3) = "Computer Name - Online"
$WS.Cells.Item(1,4) = "Computer Name - Offline"
 
$counter = 2
$CompStatus = @()

$Comps = Get-Content -Path "FilePath\ComputerList.txt"
$Processes = Test-Connection -ComputerName $Comps -Count 1| select @{n='TimeStamp';e={Get-Date}}, Address, ProtocolAddress 

foreach($Proc in $Processes) {
If(Test-Connection $Comps){ 
Test-Connection $Comp
}
    write-host "$Comp is online" -ForegroundColor Green
    $WS.cells.item(2,1) = $Proc.TimeStamp
    $WS.cells.item($counter,2) = $Proc.ProtocolAddress
    $WS.cells.item($counter,3) = $Proc.Address

    $WS.columns.autofit()
    $counter++

    }else{
    write-host "$Comp is offline" -ForegroundColor Red
    $WS.cells.item($counter,4) = $Proc.$CompStatus += $Comp + "Offline"
}

$XL.Visible = $True

$XL.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs("FilePath\ComputerListPinged_$Date")
```

Comment: You have to format the cells themselves, so: `$WS.Cells.Item($counter, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 3`. Add this to your else statement before you append the value to it.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple exceptions? You just want `"offline"` in the column and nothing else? You would have to delete this: `$Proc.$CompStatus += $Comp + `

Comment: In my If, I want TimeStamp, ProtocolAddress, and Address into its own separate Column(s)/Row(s). Then my Else to have "Offline" in (1,4) and each "Offline" listed in the rows underneath.

Not so much multiple exceptions, but by each "Offline" to be exported.

Answer (score 1):

You really should have a look at Douglas Finke's ImportExcel Module, it has a Conditional Formatting parameter that works fine for what you need. You can also set RGB colors on it same as you would see them on Excel (like the classic light green background with green font, and light red background with red fount, etc). I think it will make your life easier.

Here are a few examples: https://dfinke.github.io/powershell/2020/05/02/PowerShell-Excel-and-Conditional-Formatting.html

The module itself is pretty easy to use and there are plenty of guides on Google.